# How to capture multiple, unknown number of values using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to capture multiple strings using a regex. I was hoping that $matches would contain both a `digita`, `digitb`, and `digitc` values. It appears to capture `digita` and stop. If possible, I would like for the capture to be order independent. How can I do that?

```
PS C:\src\t> $s2 = 'a=3 c=5 b=4'
PS C:\src\t> $s2 -match 'a=(?<digita>[0-9])|b=(?<digitb>[0-9])c=(?<digitc>[0-9])'
True
PS C:\src\t> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
digita                         3
0                              a=3
```

Comment: `[regex]::matches($s2, '(\w+)=(\w+)')`

Comment: you are missing an or/pipe `|` before `c=`.  Also have you used regex101.com?  Great place to test. https://regex101.com/r/cJbox4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's **`-match` operator only ever finds (at most) *one* match, afterwards reflected in the automatic `$Matches` variable**.<sup>[1]</sup>

As [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) hints at in a comment on the question, using the underlying **.NET `[regex]` class with its static [`.Matches()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_) directly returns *all* matches**.

However, the way your regex is written, *each* match would contain *all 3* capture groups (`digita`, `digitb`, `digitc`), with only one of them containing a captured value, which makes it awkward to access the results.

The following (PSv4+ syntax) instead uses:

- a generically named capture group for the digit (`?(<digit>...)`)
- a generically named capture group for the *letter* as well (`?(<letter>...)`)
- without alternation (`|`)

so that each match contains 2 capture groups that contain the captured letter and digit, respectively.

```
$s2 = 'a=3 c=5 b=4'
$allMatches = [regex]::Matches($s2, '(?<letter>[abc])=(?<digit>[0-9])')
$allMatches.ForEach({ 
  'letter: {0} - digit: {1}' -f  $_.Groups['letter'].value, $_.Groups['digit'].value 
})
```

<sup>In PSv3-, you can use the `foreach` *statement* to iterate over the matches (`foreach ($match in $allMatches) { ... }`).</sup>

The above yields:

```
letter: a - digit: 3
letter: c - digit: 5
letter: b - digit: 4
```

Note that what `[regex]::Matches()` returns is a [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection) instance, which is a collection of [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instances.

---

An **alternative** is to use **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with the `-AllMatches` switch**, which, however is *slower* - which may or may not matter, depending on use case (PSv2+):

```
$s2 = 'a=3 c=5 b=4'
$s2 | Select-String -AllMatches '(?<letter>[abc])=(?<digit>[0-9])' |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | ForEach-Object { 
    'letter: {0} - digit: {1}' -f  $_.Groups['letter'].value, $_.Groups['digit'].value
  }
```

`Select-Object` outputs [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instances, whose `.Matches` property contains an array of, again, [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instances.

---

<sup>[1] `$Matches` contains a `[hashtable]` instance, whose `0` entry contains the overall match, and with capture groups starting at entry `1`, if unnamed; named capture groups can be accessed by their name, such as `$Matches.digita` in the example from the question.</sup>

Comment: Fantastic answer, mklement0. I saw that `-match` and `[regex]::Match()` do not return the same type. This makes this work. I have something a bit different, but I want to hack on it before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse the problem and do something like this :

```
,"a","b","c" | % { "$_=(?<digit$_>[0-9])" } | % { $s2 -match $_ } | % { $matches }
```

Outputs

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                   
digita                         3                                                                                                                                                                       
0                              a=3                                                                                                                                                                     
digitb                         4                                                                                                                                                                       
0                              b=4                                                                                                                                                                     
digitc                         5                                                                                                                                                                       
0                              c=5
```

Comment: This is a good, clean looking solution, the only caveat is that it iterates ~n times over the entire string where n is the number of keys (a,b,c...). That shouldn't really be a problem unless the string or n are much, much larger than the example